# Linq: Join on multiple kinds of conditions

Tags: linq, join

I'm trying to join on multiple conditions. The problem is that it is a mix of 'equals' and 'not equals'. This [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765230/linq-to-entity-multiple-join-conditions) only works if you want to join on 'equals'.

```
from p1 in context.Set<PersonList>()
join p2 in context.Set<PersonList>()
on p1.Email equals p2.Email && p1.PersonID != p2.PersonID
```

Comment: How about providing some sample code and what you have tried?

Comment: Edit: Added example.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `where` to capture the extra conditions:

```
from p1 in context.Set<PersonList>()
join p2 in context.Set<PersonList>()
on p1.Email equals p2.Email into p2j
from p2 in p2j.DefaultIfEmpty()
where p2 != null && p1.PersonID != p2.PersonID
```

Comment: True, but you can't do an outer join with it.

Comment: Your example isn't an outer join. Do you want a left or right outer join?

Comment: Left outer join.

Comment: Changed to left outer join; not testing `PersonID` if `p2` is null, but you can remove that test if you want to find all `p1` missing `p2` as well.